# Is there an app that can generate barcodes?

Tags: webapp-rec, barcode

Is there any web app that can generate barcodes for me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need 2D QR barcodes, you can use [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes.html):

```
https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=webapps&choe=UTF-8
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try [BarchodeInc](http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/index.php)

Comment: I think you meant BarcodeInc not Bar-chode.

Answer (score 5):

Create barcodes: [Barcoding.com](http://www.barcoding.com/upc/)

Look up UPC codes: [upcdatabase.com](http://www.upcdatabase.com/itemform.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The [barcode site](http://www.mribti.com/barcode/sample.php) at mribti.com has many options avalable.

It's also used on the [Barcode Label Printer - Free Online Barcode Generator](http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/index.php) tool on barcodesinc.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a pure ASP barcode generator source here:
http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8817&lngWId=4

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best online generator for 2D-barcodes (of any type, not just QR) is http://keremerkan.net/qr-code-and-2d-code-generator/

Answer (score 0):

My new site [blinked.in](https://blinked.in) might have what you're looking for. It's entirely devoted to the subject of barcodes (UPCs and EANs), amongst the sites features:

- [Renderering as PNG / SVG](https://blinked.in/tools/render)
- Batch validation
- A constantly expanding, 15M entry product database
- Search
- A public API
- A Windows Phone 8 App
- A Windows 8 App

We're still very early in our development - there's a dedicated alpha status page that shows how we're doing!

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The question was "Is there any web app that can generate barcodes for me?" - some of the other answers have given links to renderers and dbs on different sites. I'm building a web app entirely focused on barcodes, validation, rendering, catalouging and analysing. I thought it relevant to answer with a link and details. Apologies if this is not answering the question, I'll reword it. Can you down vote the similar answers as well please?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications !!